# Correct syntax for scoped summarise and n()

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to find the correct syntax for a scoped `summarise` function (using dplyr 1.0.2).

Here is my unscoped version:

```r
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am, gear) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(disp), n = n(), prop = sum(disp) / n())
```

But the scoped version doesn't work, I've tried different options without success:

```r
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am, gear) %>%
  summarise_if(is.double, list(sum = sum(), n = n(), prop = sum() / n()))

Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.
```

This one doesn't work either

```r
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am, gear) %>%
  summarise_if(is.double, ~ sum(.x), ~ n(), ~sum() / n())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the newer version, we can use `across` instead of `_if` suffix

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
     group_by(am, gear) %>%
     summarise(across(where(is.double),   list(sum = ~ sum(.),
           n = ~ n(), prop = ~ sum(.)/n())), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 29
#     am  gear mpg_sum mpg_n mpg_prop cyl_sum cyl_n cyl_prop disp_sum disp_n disp_prop hp_sum  hp_n hp_prop drat_sum drat_n drat_prop wt_sum
 # <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <int>    <dbl>   <dbl> <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <int>     <dbl>  <dbl> <int>   <dbl>    <dbl>  <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     0     3   242.     15     16.1     112    15     7.47    4894.     15      326.   2642    15   176.      47.0     15      3.13   58.4
#2     0     4    84.2     4     21.0      20     4     5        623.      4      156.    403     4   101.      15.4      4      3.86   13.2
#3     1     4   210.      8     26.3      36     8     4.5      854.      8      107.    671     8    83.9     33.1      8      4.13   18.2
#4     1     5   107.      5     21.4      30     5     6       1012.      5      202.    978     5   196.      19.6      5      3.92   13.2
# … with 11 more variables: wt_n <int>, wt_prop <dbl>, qsec_sum <dbl>, qsec_n <int>, qsec_prop <dbl>, vs_sum <dbl>, vs_n <int>, vs_prop <dbl>,
#   carb_sum <dbl>, carb_n <int>, carb_prop <dbl>
```

---

Or using `summarise_if`

```
mtcars %>%
   group_by(am, gear) %>%
   summarise_if(is.double, list(sum = ~sum(.), n = ~n(), prop = ~sum(.) / n()))
# A tibble: 4 x 29
# Groups:   am [2]
#     am  gear mpg_sum cyl_sum disp_sum hp_sum drat_sum wt_sum qsec_sum vs_sum carb_sum mpg_n cyl_n disp_n  hp_n drat_n  wt_n qsec_n  vs_n
#  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl> <int> <int>  <int> <int>  <int> <int>  <int> <int>
#1     0     3   242.      112    4894.   2642     47.0   58.4    265.       3       40    15    15     15    15     15    15     15    15
#2     0     4    84.2      20     623.    403     15.4   13.2     80.1      4       12     4     4      4     4      4     4      4     4
#3     1     4   210.       36     854.    671     33.1   18.2    147.       6       16     8     8      8     8      8     8      8     8
#4     1     5   107.       30    1012.    978     19.6   13.2     78.2      1       22     5     5      5     5      5     5      5     5
# … with 10 more variables: carb_n <int>, mpg_prop <dbl>, cyl_prop <dbl>, disp_prop <dbl>, hp_prop <dbl>, drat_prop <dbl>, wt_prop <dbl>,
#   qsec_prop <dbl>, vs_prop <dbl>, carb_prop <dbl>
```

---

Using `n` for all columns give the same output because it is the count for each group and it doesn't change.  It may be better to have it outside the `across` (and that is one of the flexibility of using `across`)

```
mtcars %>% 
     group_by(am, gear) %>%
     summarise(n = n(), across(where(is.double),   list(sum = ~ sum(.),
            prop = ~ sum(.)/n)), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 21
#     am  gear     n mpg_sum mpg_prop cyl_sum cyl_prop disp_sum disp_prop hp_sum hp_prop drat_sum drat_prop wt_sum wt_prop qsec_sum qsec_prop
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     0     3    15   242.      16.1     112     7.47    4894.      326.   2642   176.      47.0      3.13   58.4    3.89    265.       17.7
#2     0     4     4    84.2     21.0      20     5        623.      156.    403   101.      15.4      3.86   13.2    3.30     80.1      20.0
#3     1     4     8   210.      26.3      36     4.5      854.      107.    671    83.9     33.1      4.13   18.2    2.27    147.       18.4
#4     1     5     5   107.      21.4      30     6       1012.      202.    978   196.      19.6      3.92   13.2    2.63     78.2      15.6
# … with 4 more variables: vs_sum <dbl>, vs_prop <dbl>, carb_sum <dbl>, carb_prop <dbl>
```